# Does the (Vistoli-)sheafification induce isomorphism?

Tags: ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, grothendieck-topology, sites

Given a presheaf, in Angelo Vistoli's 2007 [Notes on Grothendieck topologies,
fibered categories
and descent theory](http://homepage.sns.it/vistoli/descent.pdf)
 there is a construction of the sheafification (Proof for theorem 2.64).

> **Note:** In this context, a Grothendieck topology is a Singleton Grothendieck topology, such that every covering of an object $U$ in $C$ is a single map $\phi:T\rightarrow U$.

The second part of the proof is the construction of a sheaf. We have a given separated presheaf $F$. Then we define for an object $U\in C$ the set
$$P_U:=\{(\phi,f)\,|\,\phi:T\rightarrow U \text{ is a covering, }f\in F(T)\text{ such that }pr_1^*f=pr_2^*\text{ in }F(T\times_UT)\}.$$ On this set we impose an equivalence relation, by declaring $(\phi,f)\sim(\phi',f')$ if $pr_1^*f=pr_2^*f'$ in $F'(T\times_UT')$. Now we define $F^+(U):=P_U/\sim$. Given an arrow $X\rightarrow U$ in $C$, we define the a function $F^+(U)\rightarrow F^+(X)$ by $[\phi:T\rightarrow U,f]\mapsto [pr_1:X\times_UT\rightarrow X,pr_2^*f]$. This is from the fiber product
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X\times_UT @>{pr_2}>> T\\
@V{pr_1}VV @VV{\phi}V\\
X @>>> U.
\end{CD}
That defines our functor $F^+$. There is also a natural transformation $(+):F\Rightarrow F^+$, obtained by sending an element $f\in F(U)$ into $[U\rightarrow U, f]\in F^+(U)$.

Now let $U\in C$ be arbitrary. Then we have the component $(+)_U:F(U)\rightarrow F^+(U)$ with $f\mapsto [id_U,f]$.

Now I want prove, that $(+)_U$ is an isomorphism?

I got the injectivity. But I'm struggling with surjectivity. So let $[\phi:T\rightarrow U,g]\in  F^+(U)$ be arbitrary. Then we need a $f\in F(U)$ with $(+)_U(f)=[id_U,f]=[\phi:T\rightarrow U,g]$.

So my **question** is: How do I get that $f$?

Comment: Linguistic note: a pair of objects/functors/etcetera can be isomorphic, but a map witnessing that property is called an isomorphism, not isomorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prove this since it is not true. The map $F \to F^+$ is an isomorphism if and only if $F$ is already a sheaf. (Also notice that Vistoli, of course, does not claim that $F \to F^+$ is an isomorphism. In that case there would also be no need to construct $F^+$ in the first place.)

Comment: Ok Thanks. Yeah, I know that Vistoli does not claim that. My motivation was to prove the universal property (uniqueness) of that sheafification. I saw that the [sheafification induces isomorphism on stalks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2781421/showing-that-sheafification-induces-an-isomorphism-on-stalks-without-using-adjo). Than I have to look for a different way to prove the universal property (uniqueness).

Comment: Stalks are not the right POV in the context of Grothendieck topologies.